# Testing validity of certain phrases in c

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

Given as data these 3:

```
float pin[5];
float mat[2][4];
float* ptrf;
```

I have to check whether the following statements are correct or not:

```
ptrf = *mat;          // I think its is correct
*(mat+2) = pin[2];    // I think its false
*(mat[0]) = pin[0];   // I am not sure
ptrf = mat[1];        // I think its correct
```

I am trying really hard to understand how pointers work with matrixes but this is really confusing. I'd really appreciated if someone cared to explain!

Comment: The third line of code is not valid.

Comment: `*(mat+2)` is the same as `mat[2]`

Comment: `float ptrf*` should be `float *ptrf;`.

Comment: The easy way to determine the which statements are valid is to put them into a .c file and compile it. The compiler will tell you the answer. If the line is not valid, the compiler will explain why.

Comment: The "third line" that's invalid is the `float ptrf*` -- the `*(mat[0]) = pin[0];` is actually fine.

Comment: @IanAbbott yes you are right it was a speedtyping error! Thanks

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for the compiler info! Appreciated

Comment: Advice that compilers will tell you if code is valid is both unhelpful and wrong. You need to be able to determine validity of code without resorting to tools (which isn't to say that you shouldn't use tools to help you with this). But importantly, compilers frequently allow invalid code to pass. For example, the statements you posted include the expression `*(mat+2)`, which is invalid all by itself since it dereferences an out-of-bounds pointer. Compilers will likely not catch this, and you will be left with undefined behavior and an invalid program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

```
    ptrf = *mat;
```

`*mat` is same as `mat[0]` because<sup>1)</sup>

```
    *mat -> *(mat + 0) -> mat[0]
```

So, the statement can also be written as

```
    ptrf = mat[0];
```

`mat[0]` is the first `1D` arrays of `2D` array `mat[2][4]`. When you access an array, it is converted to a pointer to first element (there are few [exceptions](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) to this rule).
So, `mat[0]` will be converted to pointer to first element of `mat[0]` array i.e. `&mat[0][0]` whose type is `float *` and it will be assigned to pointer `ptrf`.

**Second:**

```
    *(mat+2) = pin[2];
```

`*(mat+2)` is equivalent to `mat[2]`<sup>1)</sup>. The type of `mat[2]` is `float [4]` i.e. array of `4` float values.
In C, array names are non modifiable lvalues. You cannot assign anything to an array but can only initialise/modify the array members. This statement the violating the language constraint hence, this is invalid. Any compiler which is compliant with the language standards will throw error message on this statement.

One thing you should also note here is that the valid value of first dimension of `2D` array `mat` is `0` and `1`. Attempt to use any other value as first dimension of `mat` array (for e.g. `mat[2]`) will lead to UB.

**Third:**

```
    *(mat[0]) = pin[0];
```

`*(mat[0])` is equivalent to `mat[0][0]`<sup>1)</sup>

```
    *(mat[0]) -> *((mat[0]) + 0) -> mat[0][0]
```

that means, its the first member of array `mat[2][4]`. The type of `mat[0][0]` is `float` and the type of `pin[0]` is also `float`. This will end up assigning the value of `pin[0]` to `mat[0][0]`.

**Fourth:**

```
    ptrf = mat[1];
```

This is same as first statement, the only difference is here it's `mat[1]` and in first statement it was `mat[0]`. This will end up assigning the address of first element of `mat[1]` array (i.e. `&mat[1][0]`) to pointer `ptrf`.

---

1). C Standards#6.5.2.1

> The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))..

Comment: It's true that the assignment in `*(mat+2) = pin[2];` is illegal because you can't assign to an array type, but `mat[2]` is already an out of bounds array access.

Comment: This statement will not even compile successfully on any compiler which follows the language standard because of the fact that array names are non modifiable lvalues. Out of bound is secondary here.

Comment: _"Out of bound is secondary here."_ -- I don't think that is true. Just because there is a constraint violation doesn't change the fact that an out of bounds access is UB. I also think it is worth mention because the expression `*(mat+2)` (or `mat[2]`) could come up in other contexts where compiler diagnostics may not help. Finally, if I gave this exercise to a class I might see who just used a compiler and who paid attention to code using this example.

Comment: I am not saying that out of bounds is not UB. Yes, it is UB. Change the statement to `*(mat+1)=pin[0]` and check whether any change in compiler error message on this statement [note that `*(mat+1)` is within bound of `mat` array].

Comment: That is of course true; I'm not saying that pointing to the constraint violation is wrong, I'm just saying that pointing to the UB array access is important, too, especially for learners who shouldn't just rely on compiler messages.

Comment: Added a note as suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `float ptrf*` is syntactically invalid. I assume it should be `float *ptrf;` (`ptrf` is a pointer to `float`).

Given the declarations:

```
float pin[5];
float mat[2][4];
float *ptrf;
```

In the statement `ptrf = pin;`, the value (actually an *lvalue*) designated by `pin` (of type `float[5]`) is converted to a `float*` pointing to the initial element of the array.  All is correct. `ptrf` is pointing to `pin[0]`.

In the statement `ptrf = *mat;` the lvalue designated by `mat` (of type `float[2][4]`) is converted to a `float(*)[4]` pointing to the initial element of the outer array. (The element is itself an array of type `float[4]`. A type pointing to `float[4]` is written syntactically as `float(*)[4]`.) The unary `*` operator dereferences that pointer producing an lvalue of type `float[4]` that is the initial row of the outer array. That lvalue of type `float[4]` is converted to a `float*` pointing to the initial element of the array. All is correct. `ptrf` is pointing to `mat[0][0]`.

In the statement `*(mat+2) = pin[2];`, the lvalue designated by `mat` (of type `float[2][4]`) is converted to a `float(*)[4]` pointing to the initial element of the outer array. `mat+2` points to element index 2 of the outer array. This is just past the end of the array. It is OK to point just past the final element of an array, but it is not OK to access an element there. `*(mat+2)` is dereferencing that non-existent element so is not OK. Also, `*(mat+2)` has type `float[4]` and arrays are not allowed on the left-hand side of an assignment because they are no longer an lvalue after conversion to a pointer to their initial element. Also, the right-hand side of the assignment has type `float`, which is incompatible with the left-hand side.

In the statement `*(mat[0]) = pin[0];`, `mat[0]` is the first element of the outer array and has type `float[4]`. That is converted to a `float*` pointing to its initial element. The unary `*` operator dereferences that pointer to an lvalue of type `float`. The right-hand side of the assignment `pin[0]` also has type `float`. All is correct. Note that `*(mat[0])` is equivalent to `mat[0][0]`, and it should be fairly obvious that `mat[0][0] = pin[0];` is correct.

For the statement `ptrf = mat[1];`, remember that `ptrf = *mat;` was correct and note that `ptrf = *mat;` is equivalent to `ptrf = mat[0];`. The only difference for `ptrf = mat[1];` is that `ptrf` will point to the initial element of row 1 of the matrix instead of pointing to the initial element of row 0. The matrix has 2 rows so it is OK to point to the initial element of row 1 (and it is also OK to point to the initial element of the non-existent row 2 as long as the contents of that row are not being accessed). All is correct. `ptrf` is pointing to `mat[1][0]`.